# Unable to Select from drop down using visible text in RobotFramework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, robotframework

In Robotframework, I am able to select a value the from drop down only by using '**Select From List By Index**, **Select From List By Label** and **Select From List By Value**'.

But my xml doesn't contain any Label or Value.

So, is there any keyword to like ***Select From List By Visible Text*** to select by visible text.

```
<select name="speed" id="speed" style="display: none;">
     <option>Slower</option>
     <option>Slow</option>
     <option selected="selected">Medium</option>
     <option>Fast</option>
     <option>Faster</option>
</select>
```

I found a work around like, iterating the web-list and validating the text in it and then selecting by Index

```
@{mylist}=    Get Webelements    //*[@id='speed']/option
${i}=    Set Variable    0
${len}=    Get Length    ${mylist}  
:FOR    ${elem}    IN    @{mylist}
\    Log To Console    ${elem}    
\    ${value}=    Get Text    ${elem}
\    Log To Console    ${value}
\    ${ival}=    Convert To String    ${i}
\    Run Keyword if    '${value}'=='Faster' or ${value}'=='Navigation Commands'
\    ...    Select From List By Index    speed    ${ival}
\    ${i}=    Evaluate    ${i}+1
\    Log To Console    ${i}      
END
```

But I would like to know is there any easier way to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword [`Select From List By Label`](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20From%20List%20By%20Label) does what you want - selects the element by its visible text. 
That is, with this html:

```
<option>Faster</option>
```

, this call will select it :

```
Select From List By Label    id=speed    Faster
```

Comment: Happy to help.. :)